# Having trouble adding a for loop to program

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, jgrasp

I'm having trouble adding a for loop into my older program. I have to make it so at the end the user has an option to ask the question again. This is what I have so far 
Also just started learning for loops sorry if the question is stupid

http://gyazo.com/a71e2a0b06ed41c47d62ccc05d8ffec8

Comment: Please do not paste an image. Paste the text for your code. If you want to format it, select the code portion, and click the `{}` button above the editor window.

Comment: Remove the call `scan.close();`, after that no more input will be received. Also, you shouldn't close a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in` (it can't be re-opened).

Comment: i removed it but it still won't compile keeps giving me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't stupid, I think you just have the wrong idea here.

Anyways, here's your code, editable, and copyable

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogYears
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your dog's age in human years: ");
      int age = scan.nextInt();
      int dogAge = age * 7;
      System.out.println("Your dog is " + age + " in human years and " + dogAge 
         + " in dog years!");
   //       scan.close();   <--- don't close it, you want to be able to do it again, right??
      if(dogAge>=150)
      {

         System.out.println("Likely story");

      }

      else if(dogAge>=80 && dogAge<150)
      {

         System.out.println("Hello grand-dog");

      }

      else if(dogAge>=40 && dogAge<80)
      {

         System.out.println("Boring!");

      }

      else if(dogAge>=20 && dogAge<40)
      {

         System.out.println("Get a job!");

      }

      else if(dogAge<20)
      {

         System.out.println("Just a pup!");

      }

   }

}

/* 

this is the code you had trouble including

for(int age = scan.nextInt(); int dogAge = age * 7; i++);
{

System.out.print("Enter your dog's age in human years: ");

}

 */
```

Anyways, so that's your code. All you ever need to do is copy paste, and then highlight all the code, then press the 2 brackets symbols in the little box above the text field.

Now, as to your actual question, a simple way to make all this possible would be, throw that for loop around everything that you want the program to repeat (and a method I added in to ensure it's numeric), here is what I mean.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogYears
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter your dog's age in human years. ");

      int age = scan.nextInt();

      for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
      {



         int dogAge = age * 7;
         System.out.println("Your dog is " + age + " in human years and " + dogAge 
            + " in dog years!");

      //       scan.close();   <--- don't close it, you want to be able to do it again, right??

         if(dogAge>=150)
         {

            System.out.println("Likely story");

         }

         else if(dogAge>=80 && dogAge<150)
         {

            System.out.println("Hello grand-dog");

         }

         else if(dogAge>=40 && dogAge<80)
         {

            System.out.println("Boring!");

         }

         else if(dogAge>=20 && dogAge<40)
         {

            System.out.println("Get a job!");

         }

         else if(dogAge<20)
         {

            System.out.println("Just a pup!");

         }

         System.out.print("Enter your dog's age in human years. (Enter a negative number to stop the program)\n");

         String response = scan.next();

         age = Integer.parseInt(response);

         if(age < 0)
         {

            i = 10001;

         }




      }

   }


}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! But I have to make it so it asks for the dog age until the user enters a negative number.